# WSO2 custom authenticator for Outh2 token api

Tags: oauth-2.0, wso2, authenticator, wso2-identity-server

I want to implement a custom authenticator for /oauth2/token,
Where along with grant_type, username, password, and scope will pass one more parameter OTP and that will be validated with custom logic.

Is there any way of verifying additional parameters with external custom logic?

I can see in WSO2 docs, Writing a Custom OAuth 2.0 Grant Type but that will verify the additional params internally.

Comment: Could you clarify what you meant by external custom logic here? If you meant some outside API, you can call them in the `process()` method directly, or else you can think about setting them as another step in your login (MFA).

Comment: Sure, Let me simplify the question. I have created new grant type and its throwing
org.wso2.carbon.identity.base.IdentityRuntimeException: Invalid tenant domain null

I can see in the logs authrization has been done and then its throwing this error.